# Email Attachment and HTML Content Error

Tags: php, html-email, email-attachments, email

I am writing an email attachment script in PHP. I have successfully done the image attachment to email but I am facing issues with the html.

Two Important thing in the Email:

1. Email Content which is HTML with some designs.
2. Email Attach Images.

If i use the following header I am able to see the Email with HTML designed. But attachment not working.

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```

If i use the following header I can able to attach the images successful. but the html is just coming as it is not showing how it was designed...

```
// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
```

> Also this email should be shown perfectly in Outlook:

Can some one help to solve the issue.

Comment: Is it unthinkable to use absolute links for images like `<img src='http://link/to/my/image.jpg' />` (just a quick answer)

Comment: Don't build your own mime emails. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. They'll do it far easier and more reliably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The better way (easier and works fine) will be to use mailer class like [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)...

But to answer you, you can find some help [here](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/).

You can find another helful example [here](http://fil.ya1.ru/PHP_5_in_Practice/index.htm#page=0768667437/ch16lev1sec1.html)

```
<!-- language: lang-php -->
// Prepare by setting a timezone, mail() uses this.
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');

// Save some values to send an email, these might have come from any source:
$to = 'example@eliw.com';
$subject = 'A sample email - Dual Format';

// Create a boundary string.  It needs to be unique (not in the text) so ...
// We are going to use the sha1 algorithm to generate a 40 character string:
$sep = sha1(date('r', time()));

// Define the headers we want passed.  Note that they are separated by \r\n
$headers = "From: php@example.com\r\nX-Mailer: Custom PHP Script";

// Add in our content boundary, and mime type specification:
$headers .=
    "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=\"PHP-alt-{$sep}\"";

// The body of the message.  Use the separator with -- in front of it to
//  mark the beginning of each section, and then provide the content type.
//  A blank line beneath that will define the beginning of the content.
//  At the end finish with the separator again, but this time with a --
//  after it as well.
$body =<<<EOBODY
--PHP-alt-{$sep}
Content-Type: text/plain

This is our sample email message

Hello World!

That's it for now

--PHP-alt-{$sep}
Content-Type: text/html

<p>This is our sample email message</p>
<h2>Hello World!</h2>
<p>That's it for now.</p>

--PHP-alt-{$sep}--
EOBODY;

// Finally, send the email
mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
```